# How to write records to associated table?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Here is my entity framework structure:

```
namespace TestMigration2
{
    class EmployeeDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeDBContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }


    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Course
    { 
        [Key]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I write courses associated with specific student with help of linq?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any fancy work. Just

1. Fetch the entity/entities you wish to modify using Where/Single etc.
2. Modify the entity/enttities.
3. Call save changes on your DbContext.

   `using (var db = new EmployeeDbContext()) //NOTE: FOR THE LOVE OF GOD USE A REPOSITORY OR CONTEXT FACTORY OR SOMETHING TO MAKE SURE THAT THE LIFETIME OF YOUR CONTEXT IS MANAGED CORRECTLY.
   {
       var student = db.Students.Single(student => student.Id == 1); //Use your own condition here.
       foreach(var course in db.Courses.Where(course=>course.Id == 1)) //Use your own condition here
       {
           student.Courses.Add(course);
       }
       db.SaveChanges();
    }`

Conceptually it, helps to remember that for the most part, EF DbSets are just collections, with the special caveat that you need to explicity save changes to mutate their members.